# WPF bind comboBox to List<string>

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to programmatically generate combo box items. I'm very new to WPF and don't understand where I'm making a mistake.

This is my `List<string>`:

```
public class StatusList : List<string>
{
    public StatusList()
    {
        this.Add("aaa");
        this.Add("bbb");
        this.Add("ccc");
        this.Add("ddd");
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to show these items in

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ComboBox Height="22" ItemsSource="{StaticResource StatusList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Status}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

But `ItemsSource="{StaticResource StatusList}"` is not recognized

Comment: use an [observablecollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: also, instead of `ItemsSource="{StaticResource StatusList}"` try `ItemsSource="{Binding StatusList}"`

Comment: @Sudsy1002 Thanks for tips. ``ItemsSource="{Binding StatusList}"`` do not work, I'll look at obervableCollection

Comment: `StatusList` is a class not a property, try Rahul's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first set the `DataContext` property of your MainWindow, which will provide a default source object for any Bindings where a source is not explictly set (by setting either Source, RelativeSource or ElementName).

The object held by the DataContext is typically called a view model.

Your view model should have a public property `Statuses` which returns a `List<string>`

Then in XAML you can declare `ItemsSource="{Binding Statuses}"`

`Statuses` may also be declared as `ObservableCollection<string>` in case you want the UI to updated when elements are added or removed.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on ViewModel? How can I set it?

Comment: Basically ViewModel we refer more in context of MVVM pattern. Let it be some class say `EmployeeViewModel`. You can set datacontext for your view in your code behind .cs file constructor as `this.DataContext=new EmployeeViewModel()` 'EmployeeViewModel' is expected to expose public property say `Statuses` which can return `List<string>`

Answer (score 1):

`{StaticResource StatusList}` - StatusList here is not type name, it is a resource key.

for {StaticResource} to work it should be defined somethere:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <local:StatusList x:Key="StatusList"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

`local` is an alias for namespace where `StatusList` is declared. `local` should be declared in xaml using `xmlns`

Comment: stupid question, but Where can I use ``<Window.Resources>`` without getting an error? I tried to add it to ``<Grid.Resources>`` before asking a question, but it is not recognized.

Comment: Even if I add ``<Window.Resources>`` after ``<Grid>`` tag, the warning appears that I'm missing assembly reference.